# iOS8 layoutMargin being ignored

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I produce several views, all programmatically. There is one superview and the rest are subviews of this superview.

I set layoutMargins on the superview:

```
mySuper.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10);
mySuper.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true;
```

Then I setup the subviews like so:

```
mySub = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0));
mySuper.addSubview(mySub);
```

The goal is to have `mySub` placed 10 points from the top and left. Or in general, override what the `x` and `y` 0 points are for `mySuper`.

This isn't working though. Instead `mySub` is being placed against the top and left edges. Am I misunderstanding what layoutMargins is suppose to do? I'm just starting to learn iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`layoutMargin`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins) is for Auto Layout only. for example

```
mySuper.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

let mySub = UILabel()
mySuper.addSubview(mySub)
mySub.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

mySuper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySub, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mySuper, attribute: .TopMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) )
mySuper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySub, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mySuper, attribute: .LeftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) )
/* OR
mySuper.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[subview]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["subview":mySub]))
mySuper.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[subview]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["subview":mySub]))
*/
mySub.text = "Label"
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize it required auto layout. Thanks.